# Dataset of hand images and keypoints

Tags: data-request

Is there any FingerSpelling Dataset like this one, that includes coordinates of keypoints on fingers ?

[image]

Something like this, but for a hand
[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to ask a psycholinguist who does work on signed language production and perception- they use this type of data while developing stimuli for experiments